# Filter Apache Spark Log4J Messages to keep only those which contain specific string

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have some code written in Java which uses Apache Spark and I want to disable all Log4j log messages levels (ERROR, WARN, etc) and keep only INFO level ones that contain a specific string. In other words, I have these logs:

```
19/04/21 19:09:40 INFO Instrumentation: [e10c0eb5] {"seed":26,"impurity":"entropy","featuresCol":"indexedFeatures","maxDepth":5,"labelCol":"indexedLabel","numTrees":10}
19/04/21 19:09:40 INFO Instrumentation: [752ad4c3] {"seed":26,"impurity":"entropy","featuresCol":"indexedFeatures","maxDepth":5,"labelCol":"indexedLabel","numTrees":12}
19/04/21 19:09:40 INFO Instrumentation: [d9d09329] {"seed":26,"impurity":"entropy","featuresCol":"indexedFeatures","maxDepth":5,"labelCol":"indexedLabel","numTrees":11}
19/04/21 19:09:40 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: take at DecisionTreeMetadata.scala:112
19/04/21 19:09:40 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: take at DecisionTreeMetadata.scala:112
19/04/21 19:09:40 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: take at DecisionTreeMetadata.scala:112
19/04/21 19:09:40 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 5 (take at DecisionTreeMetadata.scala:112) with 1 output partitions
19/04/21 19:09:40 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 6 (take at DecisionTreeMetadata.scala:112)
19/04/21 19:09:40 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
19/04/21 19:09:40 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
```

I want to keep only those that start with "INFO Instrumentation".
I have this sample code:

```
    /*Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF);*/








    SparkSession sparkSession = new SparkSession
            .Builder()
            .appName("Random Forest Classifier")
            .master("local[*]")
            .config("spark.ui.port", "40000")
            .getOrCreate();
```

I want to change the first two commented line in order to apply my filter, is that even possible and if so how to do it??

I have solved my problem; it turned out that I do not need any filter or appender; I just disable all the logs for both "org" and "akka", then I enable only the INFO level for this class: "org.apache.spark.ml.util", like this:

```
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF);


    Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark.ml.util").setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is going well thanks; I have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a filter to the loggers which have messages you wish to ignore.
 The filter implementation will filter out messages not conforming to a given predicate, such as the following:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.Filter;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

public class MyLog4jFilter extends Filter {

    /**
     * Custom filter to only log INFO events with the 'Instrumentation:' prefix in their message
     */
    @Override
    public int decide(LoggingEvent event) {
        if(event.getLevel() == Level.INFO && event.getMessage().trim().startsWith("Instrumentation:"))
           return ACCEPT;
        else 
           return DENY;
    }

}
```

References:

- [Log4j Levels Example – Order, Priority, Custom Filters](https://www.journaldev.com/10712/log4j-levels-example-order-priority-custom-filters)
- [Log4j - LoggingEvent](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/LoggingEvent.html)
- [Log4j manual (v1.2)](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)

Comment: Thanks, but how do I activate this filter in my code ??

Comment: You can add the `Filter` to the `Appender` of your `Logger`. See the following examples - https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.apache.log4j.Appender&method=addFilter